# Using a delegate to communicate between a UIPopoverViewController and a MainViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uipopovercontroller

I am working on an iPad app that has a main view (In this case an MKMapView) with a PopoverView controller which contains a UITableViewController. The content in the UITableview contains a number of variable elements which I need for dropping annotation pins on the MapView. These variables change depending on which row is selected. My thought was to use a delegate to accomplish this but I am struggling to implement it.

I have declared delegate in the showIncidentList method (see enclosed code).  My questions are, is this custom delegate appropriate for this desired outcome, and if so, what am i missing that will allow me to communicate the information in the delegate and call the plotCallLocations method on the main view with the updated information from the delegate.

Relevent code:

**SearchViewController.h**  //the popoverViewController class

```
@protocol IncidentPickerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)incidentSelected:(NSMutableArray *)incidentDetail;

@end

@interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> { 
__weak id<IncidentPickerDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *incidentDetails;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<IncidentPickerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**SearchViewController.m**

```
#import "TwitterSearchViewController.h"
#import "CallViewController.h"

@implementation SearchViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize incidentDetails= _incidentDetails;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

_incidentDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[textItems objectAtIndex:0], [textItems objectAtIndex:1], lat, lon, nil];     //textItems is an NSArray of parsed JSON data, lat and lon are int's

 NSLog(@"_delegate = %@", _delegate);
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(incidentSelected:)]) {
            NSMutableArray *incidentDet = _incidentDetails;
            [_delegate incidentSelected:incidentDet];
 NSLog(@"incidentDetail ----> %@", incidentDet);
} 

@end
```

**CallViewController.h**    //MainViewController

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface CallViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, IncidentPickerDelegate> {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *incidnetListPopover;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SearchViewController *incidentPicker;

-(IBAction)showIncidentList:(id)sender;
```

**CallViewController.m**

```
#import "CallViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@implementation CallViewController

@synthesize incidnetListPopover = _incidnetListPopover;
@synthesize incidentPicker = _incidentPicker;

UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                              bundle:nil];

if (_incidentPicker == nil) {
    self.incidentPicker = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchViewController"];
    _incidentPicker.delegate = self;

    self.incidnetListPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                initWithContentViewController:_incidentPicker];               
}

[self.incidnetListPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}


- (void)incidentSelected:(NSMutableArray *)incidentDetail {


//    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
//      [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];

NSLog(@"plotCall called");
NSNumber * latitude = [incidentDetail objectAtIndex:2];
NSNumber * longitude = [incidentDetail objectAtIndex:3];
NSString * name = [incidentDetail objectAtIndex:1];
NSString * address = [incidentDetail objectAtIndex:0];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;  

CallLocation *annotation = [[CallLocation alloc] initWithName:name address:address coordinate:coordinate];
[_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];  

[self.incidnetListPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom delegate approach is fine for this situation.

The main problem is that `CallViewController` does not implement the exact method specified in the `IncidentPickerDelegate` protocol which is `incidentSelected:`.  *(By the way, I assume "TwitterSearchViewController" is a typo and should be "SearchViewController" or vice versa.)*

Even though `CallViewController` has the method `plotCallLocations:` which also takes an array, it is not named **exactly** `incidentSelected:` (it needs to be).

You should be getting some compiler warnings about this.

So when the `SearchViewController` calls that protocol method, it probably crashes with an "unrecognized selector" error.

Here are some solutions (first one is the easiest):

- In `CallViewController`, change `plotCallLocations:` to `incidentSelected:`
- In the protocol, change `incidentSelected:` to `plotCallLocations:`
- In `CallViewController`, add a `incidentSelected:` method and from there, call `plotCallLocations:`

Separately (not causing an issue but), in `SearchViewController`, instead of checking if the delegate is `nil`, it's better to check if the delegate actually has the method you're about to call using `respondsToSelector:`.

To do this, first you'll have to make `IncidentPickerDelegate` implement the `NSObject` protocol:

```
@protocol IncidentPickerDelegate<NSObject>
```

Now in `SearchViewController`, instead of checking if the delegate is `nil`:

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(incidentSelected:)])
```

Comment: Curiously, when the method name and the delegate names were different I wasn't getting any compiler warnings or errors.  I have updated my code and the above to reflect your suggested changes.  No luck so far in getting the incidentSelected method to run. Notice I have an NSLog to test if the code is ever accessed and its not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Put a breakpoint or NSLog in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and make sure that code is running as expected.  Check if it passes the "respondsToSelector" condition.

Comment: It seems to. I logged the output just passed the respondsToSelector condition and the NSMutableArray contents were logged in the console.

Comment: Do you mean it did not pass that condition?  Right before the respondsToSelector check, put `NSLog(@"_delegate = %@", _delegate);` add see what it says.

Comment: I don't see any reason it should be null.  Before the presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem, put `NSLog(@"_incidentPicker.delegate = %@", _incidentPicker.delegate);`.

Comment: from the console: _incidentPicker.delegate = <CallViewController: 0xdc28a30>

Comment: Ok so somewhere along the way, it becomes null.  Are you doing anything else with the _delegate variable in SearchViewController?

Comment: Ok I discovered a problem. There was leftover storyboard popover segue which was handling the popover and its contents. Is it possible to set the delegate and use a storyboard segue? It would save some time doing the table cell customization programatically.

Comment: I was able to init the popoverViewController from the StoryBoard. Code updated above and everything is working great.  Thank you for your help!